# wcf сервис, как сохранять юзеров?

Tags: c#, list, wcf

Я пишу программу, которая сохраняет юзеров в лист и потом может найти этого сохранённого юзера, использую WinForm. вот код:

```
public class AppService : IAppService
{

    List<ServerUser> users = new List<ServerUser>();

            
    public void SaveUser(string name, string secondName, string nameOfFamily, string faculty, int age, int co

urse)
        {
            ServerUser user = new ServerUser()
            {
                Name = name,
                SecondName = secondName,
                NameOfFamily = nameOfFamily,
                Faculty = faculty,
                Age = age,
                Course = course
            };

            users.Add(user);
        }

        public string ShowInfoByName(string name)
        {
            var user = users.FirstOrDefault(n => n.Name == name);
            if (user != null)
            {
                return $"{user.Name} {user.SecondName} {user.Age} {user.Faculty} {user.Age} {user.Course}";
            }
            else
            {
                return "user not found";
            }
            
        }
    }
```

Вот кнопки:

```
private void btnCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AppServiceClient client = new AppServiceClient();
    string Name = tbName.Text;
    string SecondName = tbSecondName.Text;
    string NameOfFamily = tbNameOfFamily.Text;
    string Faculty = tbFaculty.Text;
    string Age = tbAge.Text;
    string Course = tbCourse.Text;


    client.SaveUser(Name, SecondName, NameOfFamily, Faculty, int.Parse(Age), int.Parse(Course));

}

private void btnShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AppServiceClient client = new AppServiceClient();
    lbRes.Text = client.ShowInfoByName(tbName.Text);
}
```

Подскажите как сделать так, чтобы эти юзеры хранились в листе, а не удалялись оттуда, я сохраняю юзера, он там, затем нажимаю кнопку показать юзера и создаётся новый лист users и соответственно юзера в нём уже нет.. где мне создавать лист тогда или может как-то хранить по-другому?

Comment: А причем здесь `wcf`? Надо сделать `AppServiceClient client` приватным полем класса формы и инициализировать в конструкторе формы.

Comment: AppServiceClient client приватным полем класса формы - cсделал, ничего не поменялось, создаю юзера, добавляю его в лист, а затем, когда нажимаю кнопку показать юзера, то в коде создаётя новый лист, а тот с моим юзером вообще удаляется, как быть?

Comment: крч я создал отдельный класс, в котором создал это коллекцию юзеров и теперь всё заработало))))

Comment: `то в коде создаётя новый лист,` - это неправильно, я когда писал сделать приватным полем, то подразумевал, что `client = new AppServiceClient();` должно быть сделано один раз в конструкторе формы, а не всякий раз при нажатии кнопок.